# 'Failed to download `marmalade' archive', but I see the list in Wireshark

Tags: emacs, marmalade, aquamacs

I've got 129 packets from `marmalade-repo.org` , many of which list Marmalade package entries, in my Wireshark log.  I'm not behind a proxy and `HTTP_PROXY` is unset.  And ELPA (at  'http://tromey.com/elpa/') works fine.

But I get:

```
Failed to download `marmalade' archive
```

every time.

I'm on Max OS X Mavericks, all-up-to-date, with Aquamacs, and using the `package.el` (byte-compiled) as described here: http://marmalade-repo.org/ (since I am on < Emacs 24).

M-x version:

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0, NS apple-appkit-1187.37) of 2013-06-13 on acs-trailblazer.ist.psu.edu - Aquamacs Distribution 2.5
```

What are the next troubleshooting steps I should take?

Comment: Did you try again some hours later?  Marmalade is known for its outtages andyou may just have hit another one of these.  Besides, please consider to update Aquamacs, or use GNU Emacs. Emacs 23 8s quite old now, and many packages do not support it anymore.

Comment: Instead of Aquamacs, I strongly recommend [this Emacs 24.3 port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port), which includes good support for the OS X platform without trying to Frankenstein Emacs into alien UI conventions.

Comment: lunaryon - Yes I tried just now and last night, but no luck.  Note that Marmalade is serving out the package list, but there is some configuration issue that prevents the whole operation from succeeding.

Comment: Aaron Miller - I just checked and yes marmalade does work on the 24.3 port.  I agree that's a good port.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken Aaron Miller's suggestion and fully migrated to the OS X port of Emacs 24.3 .

I do miss being able to use the 'command' key to go to the top of the current file, and the slightly smoother gui of Aquamacs, but it's no doubt a great port.  Due to the issue with Marmalade, Emacs 23.4 won't work with some of the packages I now need (unless they were hand-built).